# Suppose 2 linear transformations $T$ and $L$, if $[T]_B = [L]_B$, does this mean $T = L$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have 2 linear transformations $T$ and $L$.

Suppose as well that we have a basis $B$ that $[T]_B = [L]_B$

Now does this mean that $T = L$?

Comment: Why do you have doubts?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I guess I am thinking there could be a possibility $T(b_i) = L(b_i)$ where $T\neq L$ making at least $[T(b_i)]_B =  ]L(b_i)]_B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for two linear maps to be equal for all the basis vectors $\{e_i\}_i$ but not be equal. Consider:
$$T(\mathrm v)-L(\mathrm v) \\ =T(v^i\mathrm e_i)-L(v^i\mathrm e_i) \\ =v^iT(\mathrm e_i)-v^iL(\mathrm e_i) \\ =v^i(T(\mathrm e_i)-L(\mathrm e_i)) \\ =v^i\cdot 0 \\ =0.$$